# Insert multiple pages before body with bookdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I am rendering a pdf book with bookdown and have a manual front page created by frontpage.tex. In my index.Rmd file, i specify the output in the YAML like this:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    includes:
      before_body: frontpage.tex
      in_header: preamble.tex
```

I would, however, like to have multiple pages before the Table of Contents, such as the quote page, acknowledgements etc. The quote page should not include any header, just the quote itself.

Is this possible by extending the frontpage.tex to multiple pages?
The frontpage.tex looks like this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}

       \Huge

       \textbf{Title}

       \vspace{0.5cm}

       \LARGE
       \textbf{Subtitle}

   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

I tried to add \newpage and continue on a new blank page, then added another \vspace, but the text appears at the top of the page no matter what i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add multiple `titlepage` environments into the `frontpage.tex` file, e.g.

```
{
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}

       \Huge

       \textbf{Title}

       \vspace{0.5cm}

       \LARGE
       \textbf{Subtitle}

   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}

       \Huge

       \textbf{AnotherTitle}

       \vspace{0.5cm}

       \LARGE
       \textbf{Subtitle}

   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seem to work. However, bookdown seem to create a blank page with a page number after each environment. How can I remove the page numbers from these blank pages? (I want the pages there, as they make sure the text goes on the right page, not the left)